# Pointer, could not print value

Tags: c++, list, pointers, struct

may i know why if i'll get something like address from the output.
Can anyone tell me how to make it output as a value?
I'm new to pointer and going to do linked list.

```
struct node{
    int x;
    node *next;
};

int main(){

    node *root;     

    root = new node; 
    root->next = 0;  

    root->x = 5;
    cout << root << endl;

    return 0;           
}
```

Comment: Related: There's no difference between `structs` and `classes` in C++ (except for default visibility). You should provide a constructor for `node` so that it sets `x=0` and `next=NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as you assigned value to x

```
cout << root->x << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well if you really wanted to, you could overload `operator<<` to output the value of the node class/struct, I'm currently not near a compiler but I assume it would go something as so:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const node* myNode)
{
    os << myNode->x;
    return os;
}
```

//Usage:

```
std::cout << root << std::endl;
```

Though if you just want to get the value in the simplest way possible, you could always just use
operator-> as shown below:

```
std::cout << root->x << std::endl;
```

Comment: passing a pointer to `cout` and getting value it's pointing to is unusual, IMO better way is taking a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I wasn't near a compiler and want to make sure the answer was correct and clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can also access value of `x` as:

```
cout<<(*root).x<<endl;
```